# Octave GUI doesn't come up on windows 10 x64

Tags: windows-10, installation, octave

(A) I installed Octave 4.4.1 on my machine running Windows 10 x64 version. I installed it at d:\Octave.

(B) When I click the desktop shortcut "GNU Octave (GUI)" after installation, it opens up Octave.vbs file instead of opening the GUI.

(C) I can start the CLI version though by double-clicking "D:\Octave\bin\octave-cli.exe". Nothing happens if I click the desktop shortcut "GNU Octave (CLI)".

(D) I tried starting "Start GUI" from octave command line. I got the following error:

```
      octave:1> start GUI
      error: 'start' undefined near line 1 column 1
```

(E) I have installed JRE before installing Octave (using "jre-8u201-windows-x64.exe"). In the command prompt, I can successfully run java command. The following is the output of "java-version":

```
    C:>java -version
    java version "1.8.0_201"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

Any hint/help is appreciated.

Comment: They `octave --gui` or `octave --force-gui`

Comment: This sure works. Thanks a lot.  Any idea why the shortcut not working? In fact, I examined the running octave window with process explorer and then created a shortcut with "c:\octave\bin\octave-gui.exe --gui --gui" as "Target" and "c:\octave\bin" as "Start in". The short cut doesn't work.

Comment: I pinned it to task bar and that didn't work either. for the latter, the target is "C:\\octave\octave.vbs --force-gui" and "Star in" is "%USERPROFILE%" the same as those for the installer created short cut. Though you have solved my problem, I am trying to understand if I should submit a defct on octave installer.

Comment: Send this defect to the developers

Answer (score 1):

By raising the defect on octave installer, I got the root cause. Refer to [bug #55635: Octave GUI doesn't come up on windows 10 x64](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?55635)

> In my machine, the application for vbs file type is notepad. Hence
>   running the script opens it in notepad instead of executing it. If the
>   script is executed, then it surely opens the octave GUI.